# Count number of connections in each network using DAX

Tags: filter, powerbi, network-programming, dax, nodes

I have a dataset like this in Power BI with connections between "Participant ID" Column and "Knows Participant":

| Participant ID | Knows Participant |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 353 |
| 111 | **777** |
| 111 | **112** |
| 111 | 249 |
| 112 | 143 |
| 112 | 144 |
| 113 | **111** |
| 113 | 244 |
| 114 | NaN |
| 115 | **113** |
| ... | ... |
| 777 | **111** |
| 777 | 398 |
| 777 | **114** |
| 778 | NaN |
| 779 | **112** |
| 3499 | NaN |

I've build Network chart. However, there are a lot of 1-1 connections that are not very useful for visualization, so I want to exclude them (see image):[image]

Is it possible to count a number of connections in each network using DAX and then use this value to filter out all nodes with only 1 connection (red circled)? Or maybe filter out 1 connection nodes using another approach?

I've tried to make a calculated column using DAX:

```
Connection Column = COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(Table, 
    EARLIER(Table[Knows Participant])=Table[Knows Participant])
)
```

However, it only shows duplicate values in "Knows Participant" Column, but not number of connections in each network.

Example of desired output:

| Participant ID | Knows Participant | Number of Connections in the Network |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 353 | 4 |
| 353 | 444 | 4 |
| 444 | 551 | 4 |
| 551 | 987 | 4 |
| 112 | 143 | 1 |
| 220 | 190 | 1 |
| 333 | 337 | 2 |
| 337 | 410 | 2 |
| 765 |  | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

You need the PATH functions as you're essentially trying to flatten a hierarchy and then exclude certain parts of it. The following help page gives a good rundown of the approach to take.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/understanding-functions-for-parent-child-hierarchies-in-dax

Comment: PATH function gives an error: "The value 'n' in 'Table'[Participant ID]' must also exist in 'Table'[Knows Participant]. Please add the missing data and try again". But not all Participants knows other ones, so not all Participant ID will be present in 'Knows participant' column. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Looking at your data, I think you'll need to do some upstream cleaning before you can use PATH(). For instance, you have 111->777 and 777->111 which creates a circle.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column to the table with a measure like this:

```
VAR pIdLinksCount = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(tbl), ALL('tbl'[Knows Participant]))

VAR neighbourLinksCount =
        IF(
            pIdLinksCount=1
            , -- if pIdLinksCount=1 then count neighbour links
             VAR neighbourId = 
                    CALCULATETABLE(
                        Values('tbl'[Knows Participant])
                    )
             RETURN
                CALCULATE(
                    COUNTROWS(tbl)
                    ,ALL() -- removes all filters from data model
                    ,'tbl'[Participant ID] = neighbourId -- applies filter to [Participant ID] column
                    --,'tbl'[Participant ID] IN neighbourId -- alternatively try this. I believe it is not necessary
                )
            ,2 -- returns 2 if pIdLinksCount>1. 
               -- The "value = 2" will return "result > 3 = TRUE()"
        )
VAR result = pIdLinksCount + neighbourLinksCount

RETURN
    IF(
        result>2
        ,1
        ,0
    )
```

The idea is to check a neighbor too - if it has more then 1 link

[image]

Comment: Tried your solution and it works just fine! Thank you for your answer!)

Comment: Great! Happy New YEAR!!!.

Comment: I've played a little bit with your solution and realized, that this king of filtering only left networks like 1-2, 1-3 ect, but not -1-1-1, 1-1-1-1-1 and so on .

Comment: You are right. Need to think about that. Hierarchy is not a solution...

Comment: I will continue searching... I will write back if find something useful.

Comment: I changed the measure.

Comment: please  check...

Comment: The formula throws an error in ```MAX(tbl[Knows Participant])```: "Parameter is not the correct type". I've tried to use CALCULATE instead of CALCULATETABLE, but with CALCULATE formula works just like previous version (does not shows 1-1-1-1 connections and so on).

Comment: Do you have a text type column?

Comment: is "NaN" equal to 0 links?

Comment: Yes, that's mean customer did not provided any "Knows participant ID" (knows nobody).

Comment: Yes, both columns are type text.

Comment: Lets make a new try )

Comment: changed to `result>3` and to If false=2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I've tried your new formula (however, with 1 less parenthesis in the end of IF(pIdLinksCount=1              VAR neighbourId=Values('tbl'[Knows Participant]). With 'tbl'[Participant ID] = neighbourId it throws an error "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.", and with tbl'[Participant ID] IN neighbourId all values in new column is 1.

Comment: sorry, forgot about the row context for `Values('tbl'[Knows Participant])` expression. You can try `CALCULATETABLE()` then use `IN` syntax, or `CALCULATE()` then use `=`

Comment: Now it works, ty,  however, for 1-1-1 and bigger chains the column shows 0 value and thus again filter out all 1-1-1 and bigger chains again ;(

Comment: Yep, you are right again. Lets fix it tomorrow - I have a meeting right now.

Comment: I checked the measure and you can see results - please, see the picture. can you add a sample with a wrong result ?

Comment: `result>3` -> `result>2`

Comment: I've added desired output. Provided formula counts all connections as 0 in the table of desired output

Comment: if 111 knows 353 then 353 knows 111. in you sample 111 knows 353 and 353 doesnt know 111

Comment: and how do you plan to count star configuration? Original wish was to exclude 1-1 links, if you want to change the question (?), then add a table with all combinations that is possible to check. It's possible to count all links in a group (not sure), but it will be a heavy measure and with many entries it will take time to calculate.

Comment: I do not see a way how to calculate number of links in the group. I could be a recursion, but recursion is not allowed in DAX. So, sorry.

Comment: I tried to solve this problem making a new column in excel: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH([Knows Participant], [Participant ID], 0)), 0, 1)` to find more than 1 connection and then filter only values >0. Maybe it is analogue of `MATCH` function in DAX, but I did not find one.

Comment: The problem is how to mark that the id is in/belongs to a specific net/group. Then your data should be well organized - as for me, it's not optimal to have some of id in [Knows Participant] only.